# PyQt: Modifying Widget Object from another Function

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I am making Multi-Page application in PyQt4, so whenever user does specific action (clicking a button for example) there is an update in widgets.

---

For example, There are 5 widgets and one button:

3 widgets are hidden, 2 widgets are shown.

Whenever i click the button, it will hide 2 widgets, and show those 3.

So in code, it should be something like this:

```
# startup    
def somefunc(self):
        widget1 = QtGui.QLabel("Widget1", self)
        widget2 = QtGui.QLabel("Widget2", self)
        widget3 = QtGui.QLabel("Widget3", self)
        widget4 = QtGui.QLabel("Widget4", self)
        widget5 = QtGui.QLabel("Widget5", self)
        widget1.setHidden()
        widget2.setHidden()
        widget3.setHidden()
        widget4.show()
        widget5.show()
        btn = QtGui.QPushButton("Click", self)
        btn.clicked.connect(self.SomeotherFunc)

 # My Question: (Code down below doesn't work, it's for example)
 def SomeotherFunc(self):
        self.somefunc.widget1.Show()
        self.somefunc.widget1.Show()
        self.somefunc.widget1.Show()
        self.somefunc.widget4.setHidden()
        self.somefunc.widget5.setHidden()
```

---

## Full Code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import resources

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 1280, 800)
        self.setWindowTitle("E.S Quiz")
        self.home()


    def home(self):
        pic = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        pic.setGeometry(0, 0, 1280, 800)
        pic.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/images/background.png"))
        btn = QtGui.QPushButton("", self)
        btn.resize(150, 120)
        btn.move(600, 400)
        btn.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        btn.setObjectName('btn')
        btn.setStyleSheet("#btn {background-image: url(':/images/Button1.png'); border: none; }"
        "#btn:hover { background-image: url(':/images/Button1Hover.png'); }"
        "#btn:pressed { background-image: url(':/images/Button1Press.png'); }")
        btn.clicked.connect(self.test)
        self.show()

    def test(self):
        print "Here"




def startup():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

startup()
```

## Question:

How do i modify some functions widgets from another function?

Comment: Could you post your entire GUI code? That would make it easier to help you.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting @K.Mulier Updated post.

Comment: maybe `somefunc` should be a class.

Comment: Both are inside class @Thomas

Comment: the widget in `somefunc` are locals. to access them in another method you must make them class members.

Comment: How can i achieve that? should i use super(Window, self)? @Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store references to the subwidgets on the main window using `self`

```
def func(self):
    self.btn = QPushButton(...)
    ...

def other_func(self):
    self.btn.setText('Hello')
```

Comment: I was doing it like this: btn = QtGui.QPushButton("text", self) is there any difference?

Comment: @ShellRox Yes, it is different

Comment: thanks i will check this out soon when im back, i think this is solution.

Comment: Worked without any problems! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've edited your code. I believe this will do the job. Just push the button, and see the label disappear. Have fun :-)

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(40, 80, 1280, 800)

        # You should make a 'mainWidget' that
        # serves as a container for all your other
        # widgets.
        self.mainWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mainWidget)

        self.setWindowTitle("E.S Quiz")
        self.home()
        self.show()


    def home(self):
        # Make the label
        pic = QtGui.QLabel(parent = self.mainWidget)
        pic.setText("My label")
        pic.setGeometry(0, 0, 1280, 800)
        #pic.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/images/background.png"))

        # Make a label that will disappear when
        # you push the button.
        self.myLabel = QtGui.QLabel(parent = self.mainWidget)
        self.myLabel.setText("My removable label")
        self.myLabel.setGeometry(40,40,200,100)


        # Make the button
        self.btn = QtGui.QPushButton(parent = self.mainWidget)
        self.btn.setCheckable(True)
        self.btn.setText("My button")
        self.btn.resize(150, 120)
        self.btn.move(600, 400)
        self.btn.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.btn.setObjectName('btn')
#        self.btn.setStyleSheet("#btn {background-image: url(':/images/Button1.png'); border: none; }"
#        "#btn:hover { background-image: url(':/images/Button1Hover.png'); }"
#        "#btn:pressed { background-image: url(':/images/Button1Press.png'); }")
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.btnAction)



    def btnAction(self, pressed):
        print("Button pushed")
        if(pressed):
            self.myLabel.setVisible(False)
        else:
            self.myLabel.setVisible(True)





def startup():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

startup()
```

Comment: Hi @ShellRox , please let me know if this answer has helped you out :-)

Comment: Thank you @ShellRox..
It is up to you which one you will mark as solved. The other guy has 5000 points, I have only 129. So you can choose for the underdog if you wish ;-)
But in the end, it's up to you of course.